# I have Authorization Bearer set in Fetch API but there is no Authorization in my Request Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/tasks/', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Authorization':
        'Bearer <jwt_token>'
    }),
    redirect: 'follow'
  })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The token is working. I tested it using Postman, curl in php, and nodeJS, and everything worked. I always get a response. But using this is my react app, I get nothing but error 401 which means I am unauthorized. After checking the request in the Networks tab in in devtools, I found out that there is no Authorization.

Request Headers:

```
GET /tasks/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Referer: http://localhost:3001/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,ja-GB;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
```

Is there something wrong with my fetch code? Or is there something wrong with react? I am not sure. Please send help.

Comment: becuase of "no-cors"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting an `Authorization` header for a cross-origin request requires permission from CORS.

You said: `mode: 'no-cors'` which disables everything CORS related in the browser, so it can't get permission and won't throw errors (failing silently instead).

Don't do that.

Comment: but when I remove the no-cors mode, I get following:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/tasks/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What should I do with such?

Comment: @joshua — As I said, it requires permission from CORS. The server isn't granting that permission. Change the server so it does.

Comment: thank you. I have to read about CORS first before I can fully understand them. Fixed it by following this https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9